# Prerequisites/Preparation for understanding a research paper - global solutions to Einstein field in Bondi Coordinates

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity, reading-list, gravity-theory

I would like to read this paper:

> João L. Costa, Filipe C. Mena, *Global solutions to the spherically symmetric Einstein-scalar field system with a positive cosmological constant in Bondi coordinates* arXiv:[2004.07396](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.07396)

and understand it thoroughly but I feel I lack many prerequisites. I have taken a General Relativity course based on Sean Carroll’s “Spacetime and Geometry”, but that’s about it.

I have no experience with reading research papers and this would be my first. I am currently reading “A first course in GR” by Schutz to refresh my GR skills, but I feel it would be inefficient.

I need some help in coming up with a reading list which would at least get me started, and which I would come back to refer to from time to time.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me where you feel your prerequisites are lacking. Is it mathematical background (i.e. differential geometry) or physics background (GR itself, and unfamiliarity with the literature there)?

Comment: You would need to learn some PDE, the initial value problem  and the characteristic problem in GR.

Comment: Thank you @MBN! This gives me a direction.